# If $ab+bc+ca=0$, find the value of $x^{a-1}.x^{b-1}.x^{c-1}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $ab+bc+ca=0$, find the value of $x^{a-1}.x^{b-1}.x^{c-1}$.

$a$. $0$

$b$. $2$

$c$. $1$

$d$. $\textrm {None}$

My Work:
$$=x^{a-1}.x^{b-1}.x^{c-1}$$
$$=x^{a-1+b-1+c-1}$$
$$=x^{a+b+c-3}$$.

Comment: There is an infinite number of answers to your question !

Comment: @JeanMarie, I have added the options.

Comment: What is the strange exercice book you use ? Does "none" means "cannot conclude" ? ...

Comment: @JeanMarie, None means none of the above options are correct.

Comment: Um, x can be any thing and $a+b+c + 3$ might not be zero.  So *any* answer is possible.

Comment: @fleablood is right.  "Any" is the right answer.

Comment: Are you missing some other conditions?

Comment: Ask your lecturer to change your exercice book...

Comment: If $x = 0$ then the answer is a).  If $x = 1$ then answer is c).  If $a = b = c = 0$ and $x = \frac 1{\sqrt[3]{2}}$ the answer is b).

Comment: Okay, time for me to stop being snarky.  The question is incomplete.  What is $x$?  and is the question what *is* the value or which of the values are *possible*?  The question and it is, is worse than meaningless.  $a,b,c$ have infinitely many solutions including $b=c=0$ and $a = $ anything $ a = -\frac {cb}{b+c}$ where $b$ and $c$ can be anything.  You are right that the answer is $x^{a+b+c - 3}$ which can be absolutely *anything*.  $a+b+c -3$ can be anything and $x$ can be anything.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the question is $$x^{a^{-1}}\cdot x^{b^{-1}}\cdot x^{c^{-1}}=x^{a^{-1}+b^{-1}+c^{-1}}$$

Now $$a^{-1}+b^{-1}+c^{-1}=\dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{abc}$$

Comment: Oh. That ($x^{a^{-1}} $ instead of $x^{a-1} $ makes a *huge* difference.